# How to auto Update Views based on Changes Made to Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

For example, when adding a new controller and specifying a template (MVC controller with read/write actions and views using entity framework) and a Model Class, MVC does the magic and creates a view that corresponds to every action in the controller, the views might include a form and data details.

Next, I update the model class with a new property:

```
public string Location { get; set; }
```

Then, update the database accordingly.

Now, I would like this change to be reflected in the controller's views as well; for example, a new Location label and textbox in the Create view form...etc

Is this possible, or does it have to be done manually? This could be a lot of work if a lot of changes to be made to the Model.

Comment: This is not possible. Visual Studio creates your Views based on some templates. Once the views are created, Visual Studio won't have any control on them.

Comment: you could probably do this with some t4 magic... doubt it would be worth the effort in most cases though.

Comment: If this is the case, I am thinking there should at least a mechanism to recreate the views based on those static templates.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. Everything you do in your controllers and views are to your specifications. I don't think ASP has the ability to think where you want things and how you want it.

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment.